# Abstract class as return of wcf ria method

Tags: abstract-class, wcf-ria-services

It doesn't appear that it is possible to have a wcf ria domain service method have a return type that is an abstract class.  I haven't been able to find any reference that indicates it isn't allowed, but any method that I have a parameter of abstract class type (either input or output) is not available in the generated code in the corresponding client project.

Is there a workaround in which I can make the method QryAddressByAddressId available to silverlight client to call in the domain service?

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class AddressQuerySvcDomainSvc : DomainService
{
    public AddressBase QryAddressByAddressId(string sAddressId)
    {
        ... 
    }
}


[DataContract()]
[KnownType(typeof(NumberedAddress))]
[KnownType(typeof(IntersectionAddress))]
public abstract class AddressBase
{
    ...
}

[DataContract()]
public partial class NumberedAddress : AddressBase
{
    ...
}

[DataContract()]
public partial class IntersectionAddress : AddressBase
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have found the reference that indicates inheritance is only allowed for entity types. [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707366(VS.91).aspx). Looks as though I am going to need multiple methods for each of the inherited types.

Answer (score 0):

Your query methods must conform to the naming convention, use an attribute, or both.

```
 public AddressBase QueryAddressByAddressID(...)
```

or

```
public AddressBase GetAddressByAddressID(...)
```

or

```
[Query]
public AddressBase QryAddressByAddressID(...)
```

Comment: I neglected to point out these objects that I return are POCO, and I perform an InvokeOpertion to retrieve the data. Adding the [Invoke] attribute gives me an error of operation named 'QryAddressByEASAddressId' does not conform to the required signature.